# Assign individual infowindows to individual markers, call content from div

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a custom Google map. I have multiple markers with custom infowindows (everything working, wrapped in divs and styled). I've managed to assign links in a sidebar menu to the markers, so that an infowindow opens, when a menu item is clicked. The problem is, that it is always the same infowindow. I've probably gone through every question and answer on this subject, but I just can't get this to work...

The code for the map, markers, infowindows is:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var content = [];
var map = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2171749, 7.5984075);     

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';
function initialize() {

var featureOpts = [ 
{ 
"featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover", 
"elementType": "geometry.fill", 
"stylers": [ 
   { "visibility": "on" }, 
   { "color": "#f2f9f4" } 
    ] 
  }, // and so on with the styling

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 10,
center: map,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
},
mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var styledMapOptions = {
name: 'Custom Style'
};

var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts,styledMapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

var locations = [
        ['Location 1', 46.096678, 7.2281081, 'pin.png', 1],
        ['Location 2', 46.0230159, 7.7428676, 'pin.png', 2],
        ['Location 3', 46.1125509, 7.919948, 'pin.png', 3],
    ];

   var infobox = new InfoBox({
     content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
     disableAutoPan: false,
     maxWidth: 800,
     pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-400, 10),
     zIndex: null,
     closeBoxMargin: "12px 12px 2px 2px",
     closeBoxURL: "icon-close.png",
     infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
});

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][3]
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infobox.open(map, marker);
               /* infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); //enabling this line disables correct map panning!! */
                map.panTo(marker.getPosition(0, 427));
                map.panBy(0, 400);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

function myClick(id){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The content for the infowindows is in the html, like so:

```
<div id="Location 1">
<div id="infobox_wrapper">    
<div id="infobox">
<div id="infobox_title_wrapper">
<div id="info_icon">
<img src="green_s.png"/>
</div>
<div id="info_title"><p>##</p>
</div>
<div id="info_place"><p>##</p>
</div>
</div>
<iframe width="800" height="450" src="##" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p class= "txt">##</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution for getting this to work? Is there any simple way of calling the infowindow content for each marker e.g. from the var locations = [] array, meaning that when a location is added, and a div or other id is specified there, the marker, along with the corresponding infowindow is placed on the map? Also, a side issue, the line infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); disables the correct panning of the map to the markers... 
Thanks

Comment: How do you expect the infowindow content to change?  What information will be different (you can only have one div with id="infowindow" in your HTML)?  Where will that information come from?

Comment: Hi, thanks and sorry, I'm really new to this. My reasoning was that the content for the infowindows, or rather infoboxes is wrapped in <div id ="Location 1"></div>, <div id ="Location 2"></div>, etc. I thought that the identification for each infowindow's content comes from the the var locations = [] array, where the markers are identified. And I've been working around this. Changing the 'infowindow' value to 'location' in var infobox = new InfoBox({
         content: document.getElementById("infowindow") did not do anything, but that was just a wild guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have:

1. unique ids for any html elements
2. content for all the different markers in the DOM
3. you can't call `.setContent` on `infowindow` unless you have defined it (I suspect that should be `infobox`)
4. you need to clone the node when it is displayed or it gets destroyed when the infobox is closed.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4skyrs58/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markers = [];
var content = [];
var map = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2171749, 7.5984075);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: map
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var locations = [
    ['Location1', 46.096678, 7.2281081, 'pin.png', 1],
    ['Location2', 46.0230159, 7.7428676, 'pin.png', 2],
    ['Location3', 46.1125509, 7.919948, 'pin.png', 3],
  ];

  var infobox = new InfoBox({
    content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 800,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-400, 10),
    zIndex: null,
    closeBoxMargin: "12px 12px 2px 2px",
    closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
  });

  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      // icon: locations[i][3]
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infobox.open(map, marker);
        infobox.setContent(document.getElementById(locations[i][0]).cloneNode(true));
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition(0, 427));
        map.panBy(0, 400);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function myClick(id) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.infowindow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 8px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="Location1">
  <div class="infobox_wrapper">
    <div class="infowindow">
      <div class="infobox_title_wrapper">
        <div class="info_icon">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/drive/images/drive/logo-drive.png" height="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="info_title">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info_place">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d193571.43828905202!2d-74.11808638273646!3d40.7058253631455!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew+York%2C+NY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1461436300347"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <p class="txt">##</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Location2">
  <div class="infobox_wrapper">
    <div class="infowindow">
      <div class="infobox_title_wrapper">
        <div class="info_icon">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/drive/images/drive/logo-drive.png" height="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="info_title">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info_place">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d88704.87577364442!2d7.671905434077621!3d45.990682827318246!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x478f35a2292ee5cd%3A0x400ff8840196f70!2s3920+Zermatt%2C+Switzerland!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1461437058426"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <p class="txt">##</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Location3">
  <div class="infobox_wrapper">
    <div class="infowindow">
      <div class="infobox_title_wrapper">
        <div class="info_icon">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/drive/images/drive/logo-drive.png" height="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="info_title">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info_place">
          <p>##</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d44233.88369647231!2d7.936860760323751!3d46.13844402760392!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x478f45103f606a5d%3A0xb47592074f679662!2s3910+Saas-Grund%2C+Switzerland!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1461437405679"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <p class="txt">##</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi geocodezip. Thank you! Finally got it to work. There is one small issue with this code, though. You can call each instance of an infowindow only once. After that, when clicking a marker, the map pans to the marker, but the infowindow does not show. Do you know what the cause might be?

Comment: Updated the answer, need to clone the node (.cloneNode) for it to work more than once.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!